# How to apply limit for each unique composite column value in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql, composite-key

I have a sample table structure like this:

`CREATE TABLE testcomposite (
  day text,
  name text,
  lpt varint,
  details text,
  PRIMARY KEY (day, name, lpt)
)`

and I have the data like this:

`cqlsh:KS> select * from testcomposite;`

`day  |   name  |   lpt   | details 
------+---------+---------+-------- 
 day1 |   name1 |      10 | abcdef 
 day1 |   name1 |      11 | abcdef 
 day1 |   name1 |      21 | abcdef 
 day1 |   name2 |      10 | abcdef 
 day1 |   name2 |      11 | abcdef`

Is it possible to query to get a result like this where each row contains unique `name` field with their highest `lpt` value?

`day  |   name  |   lpt   | details 
------+---------+---------+-------- 
 day1 |   name1 |      21 | abcdef 
 day1 |   name2 |      11 | abcdef`

Comment: You will have to use User Defined Functions. http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateFunctionsTOC.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    CREATE FUNCTION state_group_and_max( state map<text, int>, type text, amount int )
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
    RETURNS map<text, int>
    LANGUAGE java AS '
    Integer count = (Integer) state.get(type);  if (count == null) count = amount; else count = Math.max(count, amount); state.put(type, count); return state; ' ;


    CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE group_and_max(text, int) 
    SFUNC state_group_and_max 
    STYPE map<text, int> 
    INITCOND {};

cqlsh:test> select group_and_max(name,lpt) from testcomposite where day = 'day1';

 test.group_and_max(name, lpt)
-------------------------------
    {'name1': 21, 'name2': 11}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but UDFs are not supported in my version of cassandra. I'm planning to redesign the data model. It looks like we can apply criterias on composite columns one by one from left to right only.